# Writing a dictionary in python

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

```
from random import randint    
import threading              
import numpy as np



def gen_write():
    threading.Timer(10.0, gen_write).start()  
    with open("pins.npy", "w") as f:
        f.close()

    data = {}
    for x in range(5):
        pin = randint(99, 9999)
        pins_for_file = pin
        with open('pins.npy', 'a') as f:
            data[x + 1] = pins_for_file
            np.save(f, data)



gen_write()
```

So, this is the problem, I wrote a dictionary into a file using numpy but somehow, it only saves the first one, I've changed the for loop dozens of times and I can't get the right loop, at least I think the problem comes from there.
By the way, I'm new to python.

Thanks in advance
Greetings

Comment: Couldn't you copy the code inside the question? Because it's easier for people to get and try.

Comment: Why are you using numpy here?

Comment: paste code as text and learn how to format your questions

Comment: Anyway, I'm pretty sure np.save isn't meant to work with the 'a' option. The first part of the file format specifies the data, and when you append, that never gets overwritten, so it only ever knows how to read what you first wrote. You should be using `np.save` to save numpy arrays. Use pickle or JSON for dictionaries.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga then how can i make it that it saves everything that i want to write, as I posted im new to python, and I still don't understand it very well, thanks for the tip about  numpy, I decided to use Numpy because JSON was not working for me, still have a lot to learn bout the modules

Comment: You should look into `json` or `pickle` library. Using numpy doesn't make sense here.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks! I'll look into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, instead of opening the file inside the loop, you could just open it outside the loop.
Second, you don't need to explicitly close the file you open with a `with` statement, that's one of the point of using `with`.
So the code modification I envision is the following:

```
import threading
from sys import getsizeof
from random import randint
import numpy as np

def gen_write():
    #threading.Timer(10.0, gen_write).start()
    data = {}
    with open("pins.npy", "w") as f:
        for x in range(5):
            pin = randint(99, 9999)
            pins_for_file = pin
            data[x+1] = pins_for_file

        np.save(f, data)

gen_write()
```

or better maybe to use the python [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) module to save the dictionary, so:

```
import threading
from sys import getsizeof
from random import randint
import pickle

def gen_write():
    #threading.Timer(10.0, gen_write).start()
    data = {}
    with open("pins.pkl", "w") as f:
        for x in range(5):
            pin = randint(99, 9999)
            pins_for_file = pin
            data[x+1] = pins_for_file

        pickle.dump(data, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

gen_write()
```

Also, I commented `threading.Timer(10.0, gen_write).start()` because was taking forever to run for me.
Another approach would be to save the dictionary in a json file, which is a commonly used file format. To do that, you will do something like the following:

```
import threading
from sys import getsizeof
from random import randint
import json

def gen_write():
    #threading.Timer(10.0, gen_write).start()
    data = {}
    with open("pins.json", "w") as f:
        for x in range(5):
            pin = randint(99, 9999)
            pins_for_file = pin
            data[x+1] = pins_for_file

        json.dump(data, f)

gen_write()
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked on saving the dictionary but I also want to access one of the dictionary entries, just one, that's why I was using numpy, with numpy you can access just one item, I think

Comment: I think you can access with both approaches just the entries you want when you will open the file for reading.